# Sorting key function that uses custom comparison

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, functional-programming, comparison

Python 3 [removes the `cmp` parameter to sorting functions](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons):

> `builtin.sorted()` and `list.sort()` no longer accept the `cmp` argument providing a comparison function. Use the `key` argument instead.

That's fine for orderings that can be determined just by inspecting a single item in the sequence (e.g. `key=str.lower`). But what about custom orderings that *must* have two items for inspection to determine their ordering?

```python
$ python2
Python 2.7.12+ (default, Sep  1 2016, 20:27:38)
[…]

>>> digits = ['3', '30', '34', '32', '9', '5']
>>> sorted(
...         digits,
...         cmp=(lambda a, b: cmp(a+b, b+a)),
...         reverse=True)
['9', '5', '34', '3', '32', '30']
```

That two-parameter `cmp` function can't be replaced with a one-parameter `key` function, can it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`functools.cmp_to_key`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key) helper.

```python
>>> import functools
>>> digits = ['3', '30', '34', '32', '9', '5']
>>> sorted(
...         digits,
...         key=functools.cmp_to_key(lambda a, b: cmp(a+b, b+a)),
...         reverse=True)
['9', '5', '34', '3', '32', '30']
```

---

The [Python 3 sorting functions take a ‘key’ parameter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

> `key` specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a
>   comparison key from each list element: `key=str.lower`. The default
>   value is `None` (compare the elements directly).

The `functools.cmp_to_key` helper is [designed to help you transition to
that style](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key):

> functools.cmp_to_key(func)
>
> Transform an old-style comparison function to a key function. […]
>   This function is primarily used as a transition tool for programs
>   being converted from Python 2 which supported the use of comparison
>   functions.

This works in the latest Python 2 and Python 3.

The trick is done by creating a key function that takes an item for
comparison, and returns a custom object, which knows how to compare
itself as specified by your comparison function.

```python
>>> key_func = functools.cmp_to_key(lambda a, b: cmp(a+b, b+a))
>>> key_func("32")
<functools.K object at 0x7f6781ce0980>
>>> key_func("32") < key_func("5")
True
```

See the [Sorting HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) for this and other tricks.

Comment: Also note that the `cmp` builtin does not exist in Python 3

Comment: And congrats on reaching 10k

Comment: Immediate self-answers aren't frowned upon per se, but ones that duplicate easily-located preexisting questions and their answers and demonstrate no research effort whatsoever are.

Comment: `NameError: name 'cmp' is not defined`

Comment: @KAIZHAO, `cmp` is whatever it was defined in the question :-)